# How to receive Push but not the notification in tray using Ionic Framework?

Tags: ionic-framework, push-notification, foreground

I am using Ionic Framework for one of my project, I have successfully configured push notifications for both iOS and Android. Notifications are working the way they should.

I want the app to receive notification only if it is running and it is in foreground (I want to change some content in app when notification is received). And if app is in background or if it is not running I do not want app to receive a notification in tray or any message on screen.

It can be achieved in Native Development (like using Java for android) very easily, but can anyone help me solve my problem using Ionic?

Comment: Show your code please..

Comment: Thanks for the response, it has nothing to do with my code. I do not want app to show message in tray if notification is received (for specific notification only not for all). I do not know how to achieve this using Ionic.

Comment: Did you try something? You can do it without problems with cordova and ionic

Comment: I checked the documentation, I do not see any property to stop the notification from appearing in the tray.

Answer (score 1):

You could listen for the 'pause' event, using cordova events https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/cordova/events/events.html#pause
and then unregister the device for push messages. And then register it again on 'resume' event....
That way you will only receive push when app is active...

Anyways I dont really see why you would want to use push if its only for when the app is active...

Comment: thanks for such a quick response. Your solution is generalised, its just one type of notification that I don't want to receive when app is inactive, I want my app to receive other notifications normally.
For more clarity, I do not want app to show message in tray if notification is received (for specific notification only not for all).